# Running 2 mongod instances on same server - bind to different subdomains

Tags: mongodb, dns, routes, hostname, instances

I have a simple question but I didn't find anything about it yet.
I want to run 2 instances of mongod on my VPS but want to use these on different subdomains which are mapped to this VPS.
Is there a possibility to bind the instances on hostname/subdomain instead of parameter binIp and different ports in config file?

It would be nice to get some hints here...
Thanks
Tobias

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to 

use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.

Comment: how many ip addresses does your vps have?

Comment: I found many other mongodb questions here... so I was not clear about false platform...

The vps has one ipv4 and lot of ipv6 if needed.
The question is... can the mongo service bind on a hostname like apache vhosts?

Comment: Maybe it would be more more useful to use a nginx which do the routing of the subdomains and different ports of mongo instances?